# Convert string/xml representation of date into Date type for sorting within LINQ

Tags: type-conversion, linq-to-xml

I am parsing some XML into a custom `Customer` object and I need to sort the List of objects by their date property which comes from the XML. Since the date value is a string I am looking for a quick way to convert the string value to a date and then use it to sort as long as it is not empty which is possible.

```
public class Customer 
{
  public string CustomerId { get; set; }
  public string JoinDate { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> customerList = xml.Descendants("data")
  .Select(x => new Customer
  {
    CustomerId = (x.Element("CUSTOMER_ID") != null) ? x.Element("CUSTOMER_ID").Value : string.Empty,
    JoinDate = (x.Element("JOIN_DATE") != null) ? x.Element("JOIN_DATE").Value : string.Empty
  }) 
  .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
  .Select(x => x.First())
  .OrderBy(x => x.JoinDate)
  .ToList<Customer>();
```

Up until this point I have been treating the `JoinDate` as a string because is still sorts if all the dates are in the same year. Is there a quick way to convert the date from a `string` to `date` for sorting keeping in mind that some values for the `date` may be blank or empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way to convert `String`  to `DateTime` is using the `Convert.ToDateTime()` method. Your string will have to look like this: `"2018.01.05"`.

Your full code would look like this:

```
public class Customer 
{
  public string CustomerId { get; set; }
  public DateTime JoinDate { get; set; }
}

List<Customer> customerList = xml.Descendants("data")
  .Select(x => new Customer
  {
    CustomerId = (x.Element("CUSTOMER_ID") != null) ? x.Element("CUSTOMER_ID").Value : string.Empty,
    JoinDate = ((x.Element("JOIN_DATE") != null) ? (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.Element("JOIN_DATE").Value) ? DateTime.MaxValue : Convert.ToDateTime(x.Element("JOIN_DATE").Value)) : DateTime.MaxValue)

  }) 
  .GroupBy(x => x.CustomerId)
  .Select(x => x.First())
  .OrderBy(x => x.JoinDate)
  .ToList<Customer>();
```

If the value is `null` or empty or only consists of whitespace chars, the `MaxValue` for `DateTime` is taken instead. This should put the `Customers` without `JoinDate` at the end of this list. If you want them at the beginning of your list, use `DateTime.MinValue`.